# How to download multiple links from a .csv file using multithreading in node.js?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, npm, node-modules

I am trying to download links from a .csv file and store the downloaded files in a folder. I have used multithreading library for this i.e **mt-files-downloader**. The files are downloading fine but it takes too much time to download about 313 files. These files are about 400Kb in size max. When i tried using normal download using node i could download them in a minute or two but with this library the download should be fast as i am using multithread library but it takes lot of time. Below is my code any help would be useful. Thanks!

```
var rec;


csv
    .fromStream(stream, { headers: ["Recording", , , , , , , ,] })
    .on("data",  function (records) {
        rec = records.Recording;
        //console.log(rec);
         download(rec);

    })


    .on("end", function () {
        console.log('Reading complete')
    });

  function download(rec) {

    var filename = rec.replace(/\//g, '');
    var filePath = './recordings/'+filename;
    var downloadPath = path.resolve(filePath)
    var fileUrl = 'http:' + rec;

    var downloader = new Downloader();
    var dl = downloader.download(fileUrl, downloadPath);
        dl.start();   

        dl.on('error', function(dl) { 
            var dlUrl = dl.url;
            console.log('error downloading = > '+dl.url+' restarting download....');

            if(!dlUrl.endsWith('.wav') && !dlUrl.endsWith('Recording')){
                console.log('resuming file download => '+dlUrl);
                dl.resume();
            }

        });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, downloading 313 files of 400kB should not take long - and I don't think this has to do with your code - maybe the connection is bad? Have you tried downloading a single file via `curl`?

Anyway I see two problems in your approach with which I can help:

- first - you download all the files at the same time (which may introduce some overhead on the server)
- second - your error handling will run in loop without waiting and checking the actual file, so if there's a 404 - you'll flood the server with requests.

Using streams with `on('data')` events has a major drawback of executing all the chunks more or less synchronously as they are read. This means that your code will execute whatever is in `on('data')` handler never waiting for completion of your downloads. The only limiting factor is now how fast the server can read the csv - and I'd expect millions of lines per second to be normal.

From the server perspective, you're simply requesting 313 files at once, which will result, not wanting to speculate on the actual technical mechanisms of the server, in some of those requests waiting and interfering with each other.

This can be solved by using a streaming framework, like `scramjet`, `event-steram` or `highland` for instance. I'm the author of the first and it's IMHO the easiest in this case, but you can use any of those changing the code a little to match their API - it's pretty similar in all cases anyway.

Here's a heavily commented code that will run a couple downloads in parallel:

```
const {StringStream} = require("scramjet");
const sleep = require("sleep-promise");
const Downloader = require('mt-files-downloader');

const downloader = new Downloader();

const {StringStream} = require("scramjet");
const sleep = require("sleep-promise");
const Downloader = require('mt-files-downloader');

const downloader = new Downloader();

// First we create a StringStream class from your csv stream
StringStream.from(csvStream)
    // we parse it as CSV without columns
    .CSVParse({header: false})
    // we set the limit of parallel operations, it will get propagated.
    .setOptions({maxParallel: 16})
    // now we extract the first column as `recording` and create a
    // download request.
    .map(([recording]) => {
        // here's the first part of your code
        const filename = rec.replace(/\//g, '');
        const filePath = './recordings/'+filename;
        const downloadPath = path.resolve(filePath)
        const fileUrl = 'http:' + rec;

        // at this point we return the dl object so we can keep these
        // parts separate.
        // see that the download hasn't been started yet
        return downloader.download(fileUrl, downloadPath);
    })
    // what we get is a stream of not started download objects
    // so we run this asynchronous function. If this returns a Promise
    // it will wait
    .map(
        async (dl) => new Promise((res, rej) => {
            // let's assume a couple retries we allow
            let retries = 10;

            dl.on('error', async (dl) => {
                try {
                    // here we reject if the download fails too many times.
                    if (retries-- === 0) throw new Error(`Download of ${dl.url} failed too many times`);

                    var dlUrl = dl.url;
                    console.log('error downloading = > '+dl.url+' restarting download....');

                    if(!dlUrl.endsWith('.wav') && !dlUrl.endsWith('Recording')){
                        console.log('resuming file download => '+dlUrl);
                        // lets wait half a second before retrying
                        await sleep(500);
                        dl.resume();
                    }
                } catch(e) {
                    // here we call the `reject` function - meaning that 
                    // this file wasn't downloaded despite retries.
                    rej(e);
                }
            });
            // here we call `resolve` function to confirm that the file was
            // downloaded.
            dl.on('end', () => res());
        })
    )
    // we log some message and ignore the result in case of an error
    .catch(e => {
        console.error('An error occured:', e.message);
        return;
    })
    // Every steram must have some sink to flow to, the `run` method runs
    // every operation above.
    .run();
```

You can also use the stream to push out some kind of log messages and use `pipe(process.stderr)` in the end, instead of those console.logs. Please check the [scramjet documentation](https://scramjet.eu/) for additional info and a [Mozilla doc on async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function)